# Using operator+ without leaking memory?

Tags: c++, string, operators, operator-keyword

So the code in question is this:

```
const String String::operator+ (const String& rhs)  
{  
    String tmp;  
    tmp.Set(this->mString);  
    tmp.Append(rhs.mString);  
    return tmp;  
}
```

This of course places the String on the stack and it gets removed and returns garbage.
And placing it on the heap would leak memory. So how should I do this?

Comment: Why would this return garbage?  The temp value is returned by value.

Comment: Did you mean to have it return a reference? Otherwise, as Fred mentioned, it will return by val and everything is fine. Return by ref on the other hand...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your solution doesn't return garbage if you have a working copy constructor - the String object `tmp` is copied into the result object before it is destroyed at the end of the block.

You could do this better by replacing

```
String tmp;
tmp.Set(this->mString);
```

with

```
String tmp(*this);
```

(you need a correctly working copy constructor for this, but you need it anyways for your `return` statement)

Answer (score 4):

You should implement a copy constructor, a copy assignment operator, and a destructor, according to the [rule of three](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401400). Then the stack-allocated temporary will be safely copied to the storage accepting the return value.

Comment: As also seen on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C++_programming)

Answer (score 1):

if you use std::string this neither leaks nor return garbage

does your class have a copy constructor (that works)

Either way it wont leak (unless String is very poorly designed, ie doesnt free its internal memory when its destructor gets invoked)

Comment: Didn't say it leaked, I said it WOULD leak if I allocated it on the heap and returned it. 

It was my copy constructor that was failing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no memory leak. But you might want to change the return type to String instead of "const String". Otherwise this function wont be of much use